# How To Make this table

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I would like to make the following table, please see example by following link...

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpNL9.png)

Here are my arrays:

```
    $column1=array(1,9,17,25,33,41,49,57);
    $column2=array(2,10,18,26,34,42,50,58);
    $column3=array(3,11,19,27,35,43,51,59);
    $column4=array(4,12,20,28,36,44,52,60);
    $column5=array(5,13,21,29,37,45,53,61);
    $column6=array(6,14,22,30,38,46,54,62);
    $column7=array(7,15,23,31,39,47,55,63);
    $column8=array(8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64);
 $totalArray=count($column1);
```

Attempt to create table using for loop:

```
echo "<table border='0'>"; 
for ($i=0; $i < $totalArray; $i++) { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>$column1[$i]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$column2[$i]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$column3[$i]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$column4[$i]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$column5[$i]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$column6[$i]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$column7[$i]</td>"; 
    echo "<td>$column8[$i]</td>"; 
    echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Why did you convert the integers into strings by wrapping them in double quotation marks?

Comment: Have you tried to produce this table yet? Please post any code you have tried! the answer lies in `foreach()` loop to find `key/value` pairs and then echo or assign those to variables in order to build your table.

Comment: echo "<table border='0'>";
        for ($i=0; $i < $totalArray; $i++) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>$column1[$i]</td>";
            echo "<td>$column2[$i]</td>";
            echo "<td>$column3[$i]</td>";
            echo "<td>$column4[$i]</td>";
            echo "<td>$column5[$i]</td>";
            echo "<td>$column6[$i]</td>";
            echo "<td>$column7[$i]</td>";
            echo "<td>$column8[$i]</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>

Comment: can you give an example @dalelandry

Comment: I can give you an example using your first array.

Comment: no problem ,and thank you before :) @dalelandry

Comment: What constitutes when your output is black or white?

Comment: Further more where are these arrays coming from? Any reason they are not in one array and not in 8 different arrays?

Comment: my output is black

Comment: if can be one array

Comment: See my answer, I use  `rand()` and divide by 2 to see if even and then assign value to even to make black background and text white, if odd white background and text black. If you have specific reason for making BG black you will need to implement that into your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have combined your arrays into one multi level array. I use two foreach loops to iterate through the values then post them into the table.

We define a variable `$stmt` we assign the starting table tag there. Then we run the first `foreach` loop. Here we create the `<tr>` and concatenate that to our variable `$stmt`. We then run our second foreach loop to iterate through the second level of our array to get the values to display within our table row -> table data. Once we iterate through the loop we close the `<td>` tag and then close our row and iterate through the next loop creating the next row and data tag. This continues until the table has been produced dynamically.

I create a conditional to randomly assign even and odd to place class in the table and output as black or white. Not sure how you are determining that so I used a `rand()` generator and then if even do this, else do that.

**NOTE:** Notice that I am concatenating the variable -> `$stmt` 's value by using `.=`. This allows you to build your loop and store the entire table into that variable for display in your html. -> `<?=$stmt?>` same as `<?php echo $stmt; ?>`

STYLE:

```
td {
    padding: 2px;
    min-width: 1em;
    text-align: center;
} 
.black{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.white{
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

PHP:

```
$columns = array(
  1 => array(1,9,17,25,33,41,49,57),
  2 => array(2,10,18,26,34,42,50,58),
  3 => array(3,11,19,27,35,43,51,59),
  4 => array(4,12,20,28,36,44,52,60),
  5 => array(5,13,21,29,37,45,53,61),
  6 => array(6,14,22,30,38,46,54,62),
  7 => array(7,15,23,31,39,47,55,63),
  8 => array(8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64)
);

$stmt = "<table>";
foreach($columns as $key => $value){
  $stmt .= "<tr>";
  foreach($value as $k => $v){
    $num = rand(1,20);
    if($num % 2){
      $class = "black";
    }else{
      $class = "white";
    }
    $stmt .= "<td class='".$class."'>".$v."</td>";
  }
  $stmt .= "</tr>";
}
$stmt .= "</table>";
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <?=$stmt?>
</div>
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Again the output with my code would make it random which bg is black and which is white. As I am not sure what constitutes your displaying as black bg or white bg.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row_count=8;
$col_count=8;

$result='<table>';
for($row=0;$row<$row_count;$row++){
    $result.='<tr>';
    for($col=0;$col<$col_count;$col++){
        $cell_value=${'column'.$col}[$row];
        $result.='<td>'.$cell_value.'</td>';
    }
    $result.='</tr>';
}
$result.='</table>';

echo $result;
```

Comment: how to get that color black ?

Comment: How do you decide which cell should be black? for black background and white text use CSS as @dale-landry suggested: `<td class="white">...+ <style>`... _or_ inline like `<td style="color:white;background:black;">...</td>`